# Convert jupyter notebook to html without css

Tags: jupyter-notebook, nbconvert

I was wondering if it was possible to convert a notebook to html without the default css, or at least reduce it. I used

```
jupyter nb-convert --to html filename.ipynb
```

This currently generates 11k lines of css, which I think is somewhat excessive.

Comment: The length of the output file is also going to depend on the length of your notebook. Can you be more clear - do you want no CSS at all? If it is "reduced" what styling are you ok losing?

Comment: @aylr The total length of the output file was 13k lines, so if I could trim off 11k lines of css that would be nice. By reduced I mean that any reduction of the output length is acceptable, regardless of what styling is lost. I'm fine with losing all styling, as long as I can still provide a `custom.css` file.

Comment: Wow, I've never looked at one of those converted files! There are some interesting design decisions there. They include the entire bootstrap library non-minified, yet reference jquery on a cdn...

Comment: I can't seem to find a clean way to do this. You'll probably have to manually edit the generated file and drop in your own css - or script that edit. Note there is some chatter about changing to a CDN here: https://github.com/jupyter/nbconvert/issues/752